# How to use GetArray() from an unnamed JsonObject

Tags: c#, json, windows-8

If JSON is in this format:

```
{
metrics: [
    {
         "id":1,
         "name":"foo"
    },
    {
          "id":2,
          "name":"bar"
    }
]
}
```

I can use:

```
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["metrics"].GetArray();
```

Now, if my JSON consists of an  unnamed array like:

```
[
 {
    "id":1,
    "name":"foo"
 },
 {
    "id":2,
    "name":"bar"
 }
]
```

how can I get the `jsonArray`?

Comment: Have you tried `jsonObject[""].GetArray();`?

Comment: which library u r using ?

Comment: @AgentFire I have tried 'jsonObject[""].GetArray();' but it doesnt work

Comment: @vishalsharma Iam developing a windows 8 app and trying to read json from online.

Comment: i mean JsonArray refers to which library (namespace).. there might be some deserialization to type T exist which you can use..

Comment: @vishalsharma It is comming from `Windows.Data.Json.JsonArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to parse it directly:

```
string jsonString = "[ { "id": 1, "name": "foo" }, { "id": 2, "name":"bar" } ]";
JsonArray jsonArray = JsonArray.Parse(jsonString);
```

So no need to use `JsonObject`.

Answer (score 1):

Try JsonArray.Parse(...) method...